# Pyserial producing different results based on the environment

Tags: python, pyserial

I have found this odd issue where running the following code in a python shell works but running a python file with the code in it does not.

```
import serial

connection = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 19200)

write = connection.write("h\r".encode())
print(connection.read(connection.inWaiting()))

connection.close()
```

running directly in python3 shell gives the following output (which is correct):

```
b'halt ack\r\n'
```

while running a python file gives this output:

```
b''
```

I have no idea what is causing the inconsistency, does anyone know? No amount of delay seems to fix the problem.

Comment: time.sleep(1) between connection.write() and connection.read() doesn't help? Device may not have enough time to put anyting into its buffer

Comment: I've tried time.sleep(5) with no results.

Comment: Does it show anything (put the loop right after the connection.write("h\r".encode())):  while 1:
            print(connection.read())

Comment: No, which suggests theres nothing in the buffer.